# Struct undefined local vars. Where to define?

Tags: ruby

```
Twitchuserspoints = Struct.new(:name, :points)
xuser = ""

unless ($pointsstructarray.include? xuser.name)
    xuser = Twitchuserspoints.new(@@username, 100)
    $pointsstructarray << xuser.name
    $pointsstructarray << xuser.points

else
    $pointsstructarray[$pointsstructarray.index(xuser.points)+1] += 1

end
```

Where to define method 'name'? Also method '+' in else is undefined?

Comment: What is your code supposed to achieve? Where does `$pointsstructarray` come from?

Answer (score 1):

`Struct.new(:name, :points)` declares a struct itself. To instantiate it, one might either assign the result of above to the variable (or a constant as you do,) and then call [`Struct#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html#method-c-new) method on it.

```rb
Twitchuserspoints = Struct.new(:name, :points)
x = Twitchuserspoints.new(nil, 0) # arguments are optional

# or, if you don’t want to reuse it
# x = Struct.new(:name, :points).new

x.name = "seasonalz"
x
#⇒ #<struct Twitchuserspoints name="seasonalz", points=0>
```

---

*Sidenote:* using global *and* class variables is considered a bad practice *and* anti-pattern in most modern languages, including [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby).

Answer (score 1):

### Preliminaries

Without a lot more context, it's hard to see what you're really trying to do or why you're trying to define your behavior in a Struct. That doesn't mean it's wrong to do so; it's just not really obvious *why* you want to do it this way.

### Inherit from Struct

That said, the code for inheriting from a Struct is pretty simple. In your case, you might be able to do something as simple as:

```
# Define a class that inherits from the Struct class.
class TwitchUser < Struct.new(:name, :points)
end

# Assign the struct to a variable.
twitcher = TwitchUser.new 'foo', 100

# Access the struct members.
twitcher.name   #=> "foo"    
twitcher.points #=> 100
```

You can then edit the values by assigning directly to a Struct member:

```
twicher.points = 200
```

#### Re-Open Class to Add Utility Methods

Alternatively, you can re-open your TwitchUser class to extend it with a method to do something with the members. For example:

```
class TwitchUser
  def inc
    self.points += 1
  end
end

twitcher.inc    #=> 101
twitcher.points #=> 101
```

### All-in-One Approach

A very Ruby way to do this would be to declare the class to inherit from Struct, and include any utility methods you might want to operate on the members. For example:

```
class TwitchUser < Struct.new(:name, :points)
  def inc
    self.points += 1
  end
end
```

### Build Your Array of Struct Objects

Once you have the right type of object to represent your problem domain (whether or not it's a Struct), you can build an array of them. For example:

```
twitch_users = [twitcher]
twitch_users.first.name
#=> "foo"

twitch_users << TwitchUser.new('bar', 200)
twitch_users.last.name
#=> "bar"
```

You can then operate on the Array of Struct objects any way you like to find or display the records you want. As just one possible example:

```
twitch_users.select { |s| s.name.eql?('foo') }.first.points
#=> 101
```